# Получить код работающего скрипта

Tags: linux, centos

Я запустил скрипт такой командой:

> nohup php script.php &

после чего я нечаянно удалил этот скрипт.

но этот скрипт до сих пор работает, хоть и на диске его уже не существует.

Мне нужно как-то получить код этого работающего скрипта.

Это возможно? буду благодарен за помощь!

Сервер на Cent OS 7

Comment: посмотрите в каталогах `/proc/{pid}/fd` и `/proc/{pid}/map_files`, связанными с процессом, вдруг там ещё что-то есть

Comment: Посмотрел на своей машине. PHP закрывает файл со сценарием после прочтения компиляции в свой внутренний байт-код. Только потом начинает его выполнять. Поэтому в системе никаких ссылок на исходный файл уже не осталось, и придётся использовать общие способы восстановления удалённых файлов.

Comment: @mymedia спасибо большое за помощь. буду заново файл создавать.